# Вытащить данные из Json для дальнейшей с их работой

Tags: c#, json

Пытаюсь вытащить данные о погоде из json

```
string url = "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=52.73167&lon=41.433891&appid=0f4b8cc18a16a5ffd9bfa912bc7d8130&lang=ru&units=metric";

            HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            string response;
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                response = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }

            Main main = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Main>(response);
            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(main.temp));
```

Классы которые я использую

```
public class Coord
    {
        public double lon { get; set; }
        public double lat { get; set; }
    }

    public class Weather
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string main { get; set; }
        public string description { get; set; }
        public string icon { get; set; }
    }

    public class Main
    {
        public double temp { get; set; }
        public double feels_like { get; set; }
        public double temp_min { get; set; }
        public double temp_max { get; set; }
        public int pressure { get; set; }
        public int humidity { get; set; }
        public int sea_level { get; set; }
        public int grnd_level { get; set; }
    }

    public class Wind
    {
        public double speed { get; set; }
        public int deg { get; set; }
        public double gust { get; set; }
    }

    public class Rain
    {
        public double _1h { get; set; }
    }

    public class Clouds
    {
        public int all { get; set; }
    }

    public class Sys
    {
        public string country { get; set; }
        public int sunrise { get; set; }
        public int sunset { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public Coord coord { get; set; }
        public List<Weather> weather { get; set; }
        public string @base { get; set; }
        public Main main { get; set; }
        public int visibility { get; set; }
        public Wind wind { get; set; }
        public Rain rain { get; set; }
        public Clouds clouds { get; set; }
        public int dt { get; set; }
        public Sys sys { get; set; }
        public int timezone { get; set; }
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int cod { get; set; }
    }
```

И вот пытаюсь из Main вытащить данные temp, но возвращает 0

Answer (score 0):

```
Root Main = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(result);
                MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(Main.main.temp_max));
```

Разобрался)